# Drupal show search time in milliseconds

Tags: search

I have a Drupal 7 site with a large database of more than 500.000 items. I want to do some tests because the current search configuration looks for entire words, when a user write in a textfield to search and the idea is to search for partial words.

I need to see the difference of time between the two methods for seeing the performance of the search. I have been searching in Google but I don't find anything. Is there a way to do this?

The idea for the partial words is to search from the final like the SQL sentence `Where ____ LIKE '....%'` (`%` at the right)

Comment: views autocomplete filters module, also take a look here https://swsblog.stanford.edu/blog/views-exposed-filters-multiple-field-search

Comment: If it's a database search (as opposed to Solr or whatever) you can simply use the devel module to display queries executed. The query log includes timings.